# Angular HttpClient - how to access local variable into the callback method

Tags: angular, closures, subscribe

Ok so I have done a ton of looking around but can't seem to find an answer to this anywhere my code looks something like this.

Basically I have a local variable I would like to access inside of the callback function from the subscribe.

I have learned that the problem here is called closure - but how to I get around it?

```js
someMethod(){
  var localVariable = 'some value';
  this.httpService.getInfo().subscribe((res) => { /*how do i access the local 
  variable here? */});
}
```

Comment: You want to modify the variable or just read it ?

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem to access your variable in your code:

```
someMethod(){
  const myVariable = 'some value';
  this.httpService.getInfo().subscribe((res) => { 
    console.log(myVariable) // Returns 'some value'
  });
}
```